# background color over border color

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a guitar string over a fret effect with table cells and css however using z-index doesn't seem to work:

```
.guitar-string {
  border-right: #aaa9ad; /* silver */
  border-right-width: 3px; 
  border-right-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

.guitar-string::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--thickness);
  background-color: #efd5b8; /* guitar string colour */
  top: 50%;
  border-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

And it looks like this - which is wrong as the silver (fret) needs to be under the string:
[image]

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML - is it actually a table or is it a grid or... See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the width of the *guitar string* and add `left: 0`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.guitar-string {
  /* border-right: #aaa9ad;
  border-right-width: 3px; 
  border-right-style: solid; */
  border-right: 3px solid #aaa9ad;
  /* position: absolute */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.guitar-string::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  /* Plus the size of border-right  */
  width: calc(100% + 3px);
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #efd5b8; /* guitar string colour */
  top: 50%;
  /* Also important  */
  left: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="guitar-string">6</div>
  <div class="guitar-string">6</div>
</section>
```